# How can I limit the "pop-up" size of NSPopUpButton?

Tags: cocoa, nspopupbutton

I have a large list - over 200 items - managed by an NSPopUpButton. When clicked, the list extends all the way to the top or bottom of the screen and beyond.

How can I limit the open size, so that at most 20 or so items are shown at once?

Comment: What type of content are you trying to present? There may be a better way to do it.

Answer (score 6):

The solution I found was the following:

I subclassed NSPopUpButton, and in my subclass defined `confinementRectForMenu:onScreen:` (part of the [NSMenuDelegate](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/NSMenuDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html) protocol). This limits the space that the list takes up. Unfortunately, you can't just specify a size but must do the work to determine the position. You can take `[self frame] origin`, use `[[self superview] convertPointToBase:]`, nudge it over a bit and do whatever other calculations, then do a final conversion with `[[self window] convertBaseToScreen:]`.

Answer (score 4):

200 items is too many for a pop-up menu. The Mac Human Interface Guidelines [recommend](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AppleHIGuidelines/Controls/Controls.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30000359-SW54) that a pop-up menu should contain a maximum of 12 items.

You need to rethink your design. I suggest that instead of the pop-up menu, you create a single-column `NSTableView` with no header and let your users select an item from a scrollable list of options.

Comment: A typical StackOverflow answer: "You're doing it wrong!" :-)

The trouble is I want this control to only take up one line - if I can get the NSTableView to "pop up" that would be lovely.

Comment: If you can target Lion then you could use a popover I suppose. However, my point is that you *are* doing it wrong and you should think of another way :-)